# Filtering running tasks from Journalctl output?

Tags: systemd

For example one common way to check on a `dd` process is to use watch i.e. 
`sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd)`. Notably the process pid changes since a new kill command is called every-time.

Is there a good way to filter outputs of certain recurring sources from journalctl output without relying on pid ?

Comment: Are your tasks executed by systemd unit files? If so, `journalctl -u <unit>`

Comment: @jordanm No they aren't -- would you recommend writing common ones as unit-files? Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Wow. complete bounty failure. Not even an extra comment =/ let alone an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give these processes an identifier, then you can filter on the identifier using

```
journalctl -f -t <identifier>
```

Example:

```
$ systemd-cat -t myapp echo "lol"
$ journalctl -f -t myapp
-- Logs begin at Tue 2017-10-24 09:11:37 CEST. --
Oct 31 17:26:46 travers myapp[5190]: lol
```